# Live Server vs Lite Server

Tags: javascript, node.js, npm, package.json, lite-server

Just starting with JavaScript.  Do I have to have Lite Server or can I use VS Code's Liveserver extension instead?  Any research I've done on the topic leads into node.js, package.json, and NPMs which I don't understand.

If Lite Server is needed, do you install it through terminal/command line or do you have to install it in the html document you want to apply it to?  Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

They are both pretty similar and for your purposes, **VSCode's Live server will work fine for you** especially if you are not familiar with npm, node, and do not have a package.json.

If you would like to learn more about npm and what a package.json is check [this](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=gKyRqFgJt6k) out.